1D Fokker-Planck derivation for Local Volatility model
In the calibration of a local volatility model with diffusion $dX_t = b(X_t) dt + \sigma(t, X_t)dW_t$, one relies on the Dupire equation which itself derives from the Fokker-Planck equation
$$\partial_t p(x, t) = - \partial_x[b(x)p(x, t)] + \frac{1}{2}\partial_{xx}^2[\sigma^2(t, x)p(x, t)]$$
My question concerns this Fokker-Planck equation. In all resources I could find, the hypothesis from which this equation derives is that both $b$ and $\sigma$ are functions of $x$ only. But obviously, we need to allow $\sigma$ to also depend on $t$.
So my question is the following: is the proof of Fokker-Planck in the case where $b$ and $sigma$ only depend on $x$ easily extended to the case where $\sigma$ can also depend on $t$?
======================================================================
Additionnaly, I wrote the following proof, how can it be generalized?
Consider the infinitesimal generator $\mathcal{L} f(x)$, defined as
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L} f(x) := b(x) \partial_x f(x) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(x)\partial_{xx}^2f(x)
\end{equation}
From Itô's lemma, one notices that
\begin{align*}
    &f(X_t) = f(x) + \int_0^t \partial_x f(X_s) dX_s + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \partial_{xx}^2 f(X_s) d\langle X, X\rangle_s\\
    &= f(x) + \int_0^t b(X_s) \partial_x f(X_s) + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2(X_s)\partial_{xx}^2f(X_s)ds + \int_0^t \sigma(X_s) \partial_x f(X_s) dW_s\\
    &= f(x) + \int_0^t \mathcal{L} f(X_s)ds + M_t
\end{align*}
with $M_t$ a local martingale. Using the above formule for times $t$ and $t+s$, taking the expectation and substracting leads to
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{E}[f(X_{t+s}] - \mathbb{E}[f(X_t)] = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{t}^{t+s}\mathcal{L} f(X_r)dr\right]
\end{equation}
Taking $s\to 0$, we conclude that $\partial_t \mathbb{E}[f(X_t)] = \mathbb{E}[\mathcal{L} f(X_t)]$.\
Letting $(p_t(x, \cdot))_{t\geq 0, x\in \mathbb{R}}$ denote the transition kernel of $(X_t)$, we can introduce a semi-group operator:
\begin{equation}
    P_tf(y) := \int_x f(x) p_t(x, dy)
\end{equation}
Because a transition kernel verifies by definition the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation
\begin{equation}
    p_t(x, A) = \int_y p_s(x, dy) p_{t-s}(y, A)\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R},\quad \forall 0\leq s \leq t
\end{equation}
and from the fact that $(X_t)$ is Markovian, we conclude that $\mathbb{E}[h(X_t)\mid \mathcal{F}_s] = P_{t-s}h(X_s)$ for any almost surely bounded measurable function $h$, so that
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:penultian_fokker_planck}
    \partial_t \mathbb{E}[f(X_t)] = \mathbb{E}[\mathcal{L} f(X_t)] \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \partial_t P_tf(x) = P_t \mathcal{L} f(x)
\end{equation}
because $X_0 = x$ almost surely.\
Now, we can introduce the adjoint of $\mathcal{L}$, denoted $\mathcal{L}^*$ and defined by
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L}^*f(x) := - \partial_x(bf)(x) + \frac{1}{2}\partial_{xx}^2(\sigma^2f)(x)
\end{equation}
We have
\begin{equation}
    \int_x f(x)\mathcal{L} g(x)dx = \int_x \mathcal{L}^* f(x)g(x)dx
\end{equation}
for any two infinitely differentiable functions $f$ and $g$ with compact support. In particular, we can can write in terms of density: $\partial_t p_t(x,y) = \mathcal{L}^*p_t(x,y)$. Indeed, with $p_t(x, dy) = p_t(x, y) dy$:
\begin{equation}
P_t \mathcal{L} f(x) = \int_y \mathcal{L} f(y) p_t(x, y)dy = \int_y f(y) ^*p_t(x, y)dy
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    \partial_t P_tf(x) = \partial_t \int_y f(y) p_t(x, y)dy = \int_y f(y) \partial_t p_t(x, y)dy
\end{equation}
i.e $\partial_t p_t(x,y) = \mathcal{L}^*p_t(x,y)$. Replacing by the definition of $\mathcal{L}^*$ allows us to conclude.

I can't quite follow your proof (maybe because of notation), which doesn't mean that it's wrong. To answer your question: yes it holds if $b,\sigma$ depend on $t$ as well.
I'll give a slightly simpler proof below. If you're proficient in analysis you can fill in the technical conditions yourself (or otherwise look them up or just accept them).
First of all let $F: \mathbb R \times [0,T] \to \mathbb R$ be a test function such that $\forall y \in \mathbb R$ $F(y, T) = F(y,t) = 0$.
Also, let $p(y,u|x,t)$ be the probability density with $(x,t)$ the backward variables and $(y,u)$ the forward variables
By It$\hat{\text{o}}$'s lemma
$$
F(X_T,T) = F(X_t,t) + \int_t^T \left( \partial_u  +  \mathcal{L} \right)F(X_u,u) du + \int_t^T (\cdot) dW_u.
$$
Now take expectations and using the property of the test function
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_t^T \left( \partial_u  +  \mathcal{L} \right)F(y,u) p(y,u | x,t) \, du \, dy = 0
$$
Carrying out integration by parts wrt $u$ for $\partial_u$ and wrt to $y$ for $\mathcal L$ gives
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_t^T F(y,u) \left( - \partial_u  +  \mathcal{L^*} \right) p(y,u | x,t) \, du \, dy = 0
$$
Since this is valid for an arbitrary test function $F$
$$
\partial_T p(K,T|x,t) = \mathcal{L^*} p(K,T|x,t)
$$
where I have switched to the notation $(K,T)$ for the forward variables, as those are usually used in the context of local volatility.
As you can see, nowhere in the proof is it necessary to require that $b$ and/or $\sigma$ are independent of $t$.

Thank you very much! I took a first look at your proof and it looks really nice. I will accept your answer once I am sure I fully understood it.

@Noomkwah Sure. Roughly speaking the important points in the proof are the use of test functions with the specific property, and in the integration by parts wrt to the spatial variable it's assumed that functions decay sufficiently fast.
